# C# : Get list of Firefox extension on my system

Tags: c#, firefox

I want to list all the extension installed in Firefox browser programatically.

I tried to search in different places in registry, Files etc, but couldn't find a place where Mozilla stores information.

Comment: Firefox extensions are installed in some folder(s) inside (Firefox) profiles. (Note that different profiles can have different sets and different versions of extensions installed.) Start with learning about Firefox profiles. Only after you get an understanding of this, you might want to start planning on how to program what you want/need in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **AppData- Roaming-Mozilla->Extensions.**

Comment: Thanks for the help. But on my machine I could locate it under path ==> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\pkrn6dn7.default\extensions

Comment: Glad it helped.